# How can I reduce noise from plumbing in a kitchen soffit?

Tags: plumbing

I am getting ready to close up my new kitchen soffit and I was wondering what would be a good option to try and soundproof the DWV pipes in the soffit.

Should I try to wrap them?

Or should I try to stuff in some Rockwool?

Or should I try to build some kind of box with acoustic foam?

Or do nothing and just accept some of that noise?

Comment: Are you keeping someone in your soffit and you don't want them to hear you in the kitchen?

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine there would be a lot of noise coming from them. If you're really concerned about it, stuff some extra insulation up in there and and use 5/8" drywall or double up on the 1/2" drywall. I've done this in the past and had some pretty fussy customers happy.

Answer (score 1):

Are your pipes plastic (ABS/PVC)?  Plastic is noisy and can make popping sounds due to thermal expansion.  If it's just a straight run of pipe in your soffit that's bothering you, you could cut out a length of plastic pipe and use Fernco couplings (the steel-banded ones) to splice in a section of Cu DWV or CI (depending on size), using straps or hangers for support.

Alternatively, to leave the pipes as-is and just soundproof the drywall, I've had great success with a double layer of drywall with "Green Glue Noiseproofing Compound" between them.